# Issue when converting Base 64 encoded graphic image to PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

We are getting Base 64 encoded graphic image as webservice response and we have to convert it to PDF file. We used bellow code snippet to transfrom base 64 encoded graphic image to pdf doc.

```
// First decode the Base 64 encoded graphic image
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(s);

// Create the pdf file
File file = new File("output.png");
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

fop.write(decodedBytes);
fop.flush();
fop.close();
```

But when we open the pdf file we are getting bellow error.

**Adobe Reader could not open "output.pdf" because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged.**

We tried the PDF box as bellow,

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(s);

ImageToPDF imageToPdf = new ImageToPDF();
imageToPdf.createPDFFromImage("output.pdf", decodedBytes.toString());
```

This also didnt help us. Please suggest me a way to creat the pdf file from Base 64 encoded graphic image.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are missing a step here. Please try following

- First, create the image from the Base64 data as follows (Taken from [here](http://www.developerfeed.com/java/topic/how-convert-base64-encoded-stream-image-using-java))

> String base64String =
>   "BORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAAHgCAYAAADUjLREAAAgAElEQVR4AexdB4BU1dX+ZmZ7ZWGX3pHeu6goitgQDCZGjdHYu4nGqL81mmaJvdd";
>
> ```
>     BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
>     byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64String);
>     log.debug("Decoded upload data : " + decodedBytes.length);
>
>
>
>      String uploadFile = "/tmp/test.png";
>      log.debug("File save path : " + uploadFile);
>
>      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));
>      if (image == null) {
>           log.error("Buffered Image is null");
>       }
>      File f = new File(uploadFile);
>
>      // write the image
>       ImageIO.write(image, "png", f);
> ```

Please note that this example uses `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`, but I would advice not to use this but use some other open source decoder (e.g apache [commend-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) library is good and widely used.).

- Once you have the image file, use [`ImageToPDF`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ImageToPDF.html) to convert the same to PDF file.

Comment: Thanks Santosh for your comment. I want to convert the Base 64 encoded graphic image directly to pdf file rather than first convert it to image and then pdf.